# Later versions of RPMs not available through custom yum repo

Tags: yum, rhel6, repository

I've created a custom repository following [this guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/create-your-own-yum-repository/609).

Files are being served via http (nginx). I've `cd`'d into the directory to create the metadata with `createrepo .`. I can install a package through yum from my custom repo; so far, so good.

Now I want to see how an upgrade process might work, this is where I'm having trouble. My first package, that I installed successfully, is from *build-utils-20130930-62.noarch.rpm*

So I create a new package *build-utils-20131001-63.noarch.rpm*, then in the repo directory `sudo createrepo --update .`. Now I try `sudo yum --nogpgcheck install build-utils`, the result

```
Package build-utils-20130930-62.noarch already installed and latest version
```

I've tried to install the new version with a more explicit call to yum

```
sudo yum --nogpgcheck install build-utils-20131001-63
```

the result

```
No package build-utils-20131001-63 available.
```

Decided to dig into the filelists.xml file to see if the update worked, and sure enough

```
<package pkgid="c12eb685ebfedf4dd3155d0910517f3eb208dac09cc36b9e971541f038a4590d" name="build-utils" arch="noarch">
    <version epoch="0" ver="20131001" rel="63"/>
```

So I've even tried completely removing the current version

```
yum remove build-utils
```

Now I go to install from scratch

```
sudo yum --nogpgcheck install build-utils
```

yum offers me version 62 still! I've even tried to clear the yum cache `su -c 'yum clean headers'` to no avail.

How do I get my new versions available from the custom repository?

Comment: You may need to add the `--database` option to `createrepo`.

Comment: Seems like that's the default these days; from the man page `Generate sqlite databases for use with yum. This is now the default.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
yum clean all

yum -y update build-utils
```

The repolist gets cached on your yum client host.

"Clean all cached files from any enabled repository. Useful to run from time to time to make sure there is nothing using unnecessary space." [[1](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands)]

Comment: That's a good start, I can install the latest version now! **But**, what a painful process.., the next time I go to install anything I have to sit and wait for all the repositories to update metadata or some such. Is there a way to clear just the custom repo's cache, or another thought, how come I don't have to do this with 'standard' repositories?

Comment: Hmm, thinking for a minute, probably I don't ever install 'regular' packages often enough to run into wanting to install a package that's still in the cache.., that's a thought anyway. With these custom packages, we'll be installing new versions every couple weeks or so. A  quick look [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCommands) though, and I don't see a way to clear the cache for a single package or repo.

Comment: Check out metadata_expire?  metadata_expire Time (in seconds) after which the metadata will expire. http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf

Comment: Sadly I see no way to configure cache expiry time, or disable caching on a particular repository. It does look like I can get away with `yum clean expire-cache` though, which seems like it could be slightly faster than `yum clean all`.

Comment: You *can* set it per repo: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch04s08s02.html

Answer (score 0):

I've already accepted @dmourati's answer, and I'm going to leave it that way, however the final solution was a change to my repository configuration file to not cache on this repository.

```
[customrepo]
name=Custom Repository
baseurl=http://custom/$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=0
```

Notice the last line (thanks again @dmourati!). This way I never have to run any sort of `yum clean`, and caching is still in place for all the other repositories.

The reason I'm disabling caching on this repository, is that these are proprietary application packages we'll be building frequently. Perhaps in production I'll allow some caching, but we'll have to see how things shape up with the build/deploy system.

Comment: No, this is very very wrong.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Question is about the cache cleanup, not the keeping.

Comment: Turns out you don't need to clear the cache if there isn't one.